# R: How to use output of 'translate' function to write a table?

Tags: r, sequence, bioinformatics, write.table

I have a file ([data.txt](http://www.mediafire.com/view/629mzqqjtl471qi/data.txt)) that contains 2 DNA sequences (ORF):

```
data = readDNAStringSet(file="data.txt") 
data
# A DNAStringSet instance of length 2
# width seq                                                       names
#[1]  57 ATGACCCCCACCTCCATCCCCACACTTCTATCCCGCTGCCCCGCCTCTCTCCCCTAA  GPG
#[2]  54 ATGACCCATGAGCACCATGCAGCCAAAACCCTGGGAATCGGCAAAGCCATCTAG     PfK
```

I want to convert them to aminoacids:

```
t=vector(mode="list", length=length(data))
for (i in seq_along(data))
{
t[[i]]=translate(data[[i]])
}
t
#[[1]]
#19-letter "AAString" instance
#seq: MTPTSIPTLLSRCPASLP*

#[[2]]
#18-letter "AAString" instance
#seq: MTHEHHAAKTLGIGKAI*
```

then write a table and have an output using:

```
tt=do.call(rbind,t)
write.table(tt,"aa.txt",sep="\t\t")
```

but these commands don't work. I couldn't find the problem. How can I write a table?

Note: `translate` is a function from the [**`seqinr`**] and `readDNAStringSet` is a function from the [**`Biostrings`**].

Comment: What does "don't work" mean? The two vectors are of different length, which should result in a warning if you `rbind` them.

Comment: @ Ronald:  "tt=do.call(rbind,t)":
Error in .Method(..., deparse.level = deparse.level) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Comment: A shot in the dark: try not using `t` as your variable name. Try it again, but name it `t1` or something.

Comment: @ Ronald: Each vector has 3 columns.

Comment: @ joran: I tried but there is no difference!

Comment: The data in `t` is some sort of special S4 class that can't be coerced to what rbind needs. But it's impossible for me help any more because (a) I don't know what package you're using for these commands, and (b) I don't have your example data.

Comment: can you post the text of "data.txt", or a link to it, so that the example is reproducible??

Comment: @ joran and @ Ben Bolker: link for download the data.txt: http://www.mediafire.com/view/629mzqqjtl471qi/data.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need *seqinr*. *Biostrings* does everything you need.

```
library("Biostrings")

dna <- readDNAStringSet(file="data.txt")
aa <- translate(dna)

write.table(as.character(aa), file="aa.txt", sep="\t\t")
```

Maybe you want to use `writeXStringSet` instead of `write.table`.